# How does Github knows my password is commonly used on other website?

Tags: github

Funny Fact, but don't know how it's happening. Just curious.

In the setting page of my Github account, showing "The password you provided is in a list of passwords commonly used on other websites. To increase your security, you must update your password...."

It seems to be normal but once I think deeper, I don't really get how Github knows my password is commonly used by other website!

I mean in the "other website's" perspective, Github supposingly does not know what set of password is used by its' client, then how Github know its' own client password is commonly used from other website?

[image]

Comment: It means that it was found in a public list of passwords (or more likely password hashes) exposed in a security breach. Another site that you or another user with the same password use may have been hacked. Security researchers can then use these public password lists to warn people their accounts might be at risk.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://github.community/t/new-draconian-account-requirements-monitoring/122710), since Q2 2020:

> While the password you have at present may meet the listed requirements, the system also runs a check when you provide your password (during sign in, or sudo access).
>
> **The check compares a one-way hash of that password against our internal database of credentials known to be compromised by breaches of other websites or services**.
>
> The weak password message you received indicates that the password you have entered was used by someone (not necessarily yourself) on a website that was compromised, which means it’s on lists used by malicious actors in their automated takeover attempts.

So the comparison is about password hash, not the actual password.

The thread adds:

> GitHub uses both open and private paid sources of breach data in order to protect customer accounts.
> We don’t typically name our vendors and in some cases we are actually precluded from doing so by contract. The exception, of course, is where we share customer data with a vendor 5, and that isn’t the case here.
>
> We have two different responses to any matching credentials:
>
> 1. If there is a direct match - ie, your exact email and your password are present in a breach - then we force a password reset.
>    You won’t be able to use your account again until you have reset your password.
>    A direct match presents a high risk to the security of your GitHub account, and by extension, any GitHub repositories or organisations you have access to.
> 2. If there is an indirect match - ie, your password has been in a breach, but not necessarily your exact email address - we then warn about a weak password, and give you a window of time in which to change it.
>    This is a lower risk scenario, but still a risk.
>
> We’re aware that we do take a conservative approach here, and that is constantly under review.
> We understand that some people would prefer to be a little more relaxed about security themselves, but again, account takeovers create a substantial workload for us, and at present, an opt-out function is not an option.

---

> How can they compare a salted hash though? Or are they implying that they hash passwords directly?

In cryptographic systems that follow best practices, passwords are usually [hashed with a unique salt value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) for each user. The salt is then stored alongside the hashed password in the database. That technique renders precomputed hash tables, like rainbow tables, ineffective. The presence of the unique salt ensures that two users with the same password will have different hashes stored in the database.

Given that salted hashes are unique per user, directly comparing a salted hash against a list of compromised hashes would be ineffective.

- GitHub could temporarily hash the password without salt (or use a common salt) to compare it against their list of known compromised hashes during the account creation or password update process. That does not mean that the unsalted hash is stored; after the check, the system would discard the unsalted hash and store a salted hash of the password for long-term storage.
- The database of compromised credentials might contain hashes created in a manner that is compatible with the check. That would allow GitHub to do a one-way hash of the input password and compare it to the database effectively.
- The compromised passwords in the list are likely hashed with the same algorithm that GitHub uses for the temporary check. However, they may not include a salt.

From my initial answer above, GitHub might use a one-way hash of the password to check against a database of compromised credentials. That likely means that the hash used for this comparison is not salted or uses a standard salt, separate from the unique salt used for securely storing your password in their database. After the check against the database of compromised credentials, your password would be salted and hashed securely for storage, in line with best practices.

Comment: How can they compare a salted hash though? Or are they implying that they hash passwords directly?